# Cannot access external storage after granting permission for first use of app in android

Tags: android, android-permissions

When user accept read_external_storage permission, the permission would granted successfully (I saw it in app info). But When I want to access a file in external storage, gives Permission Denied error.

When I restart app and clear it from history permission works good.
But before restart doesn't work, Why?

Comment: You are doing something wrong i think.

Comment: I saw that storage permission granted successfullt

Comment: @greenapps I read that some permission require restart to apply

Comment: Pretty unclear. Which ones? Where? And if so what is the problem?

Comment: Could your share your source code ?

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I have the same problem